# Tensorflow Transformer Decoder output not giving the expected result

Tags: python, tensorflow, transformer-model, attention-model

I have designed an transformer model using tensorflow. The aim of the model is to generate a sequence of text which is ideally an question followed by an answer given an input sentence.

I have datapoints ( around 15k ) whose format is as below

```
SOURCE SENTENCE: <@>A man in the distance is walking past a brick wall painted with words and graffiti.<#>where<%>wall<?>brick
TARGET SENTENCE: <^>where is the man walking ?<~>A man is walking past a brick wall
```

I have trained the model using sentencepiece tokenizer.

For some reason, even after training the model upto 100 epochs, I am not getting the desired output. I expect the network to pick up the 
words from the source sentence and construct an Question Answer pair. But, in actual, the network constructs a question answer pair ( which is really good but the words which it user is not in the source sentence.

Below is the output from the network from the above source input after 50 Epochs for a beam search width of 15.

```
PRED: <^>what does the woman?<~>the girls are young
PRED: <^>what was the girl holding ?<~>the girl was be
PRED: <^>what was the girl doing ?<~>the man are posing.
PRED: <^>what was the girl doing ?<~>the man are posing
PRED: <^>what was the girl holding ?<~>the girl was looking
PRED: <^>what was the girl holding ?<~>a man wearing a black shirt.
PRED: <^>what is the girls are ?<~>the girls are wearing a young man
PRED: <^>what is the girls are ?<~>the girls are wearing a
PRED: <^>what was the girl holding ?<~>the girl was be for the field
PRED: <^>what was the girl holding ?<~>the girl was holding a swing
PRED: <^>what was the girl doing ?<~>the man are tryings
PRED: <^>what is the girls are ?<~>the girls are wearing a brunette
PRED: <^>what was the girl holding ?<~>the girl was holding a peace man
PRED: <^>what is the girls are ?<~>the girls are wearing a older girl
PRED: <^>what is the girls are ?<~>the girls are wearing a older
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. I am quite sure that the network is learning from the training which is very promising given  the way the output is constructed but the main issue here is the question answer is formed from words which are not in the source sentence.

Is there a way to instruct the network to mainly use the words from the source sentence only? Below is the decoder output function.

```
def symbols_to_logits_fn(model, config, decoder_tensor, debug=False):
    '''We basically need to run the complete decoder function
    :param model: namespace returned from function
    :param decoder_tensor: [batch_size * beam_size, decoded_length]
    :return new_ids: [batch_size * beam_size, vocab_size]
    '''
    print('^^^^^^ decoder_tensor: {}'.format(decoder_tensor))
        decoder_gather = tf.gather(
        model.context_embedding, decoder_tensor
    ) * (config.embedding_dim ** 0.5)
    decoder_gather += tf.gather(model.position_embedding,
                            positions_for(decoder_tensor, past_length=0))
    print('>>>>> {}'.format(decoder_gather))
    encoder_tiled = tf.tile(model.encoder_embedding, [config.beam_size, 1, 1])
    print('>>> encoder_tiled: {}'.format(encoder_tiled))
    local_decoder_pad_mask = tf.math.equal(
        decoder_tensor, config.pad_id, name='beam_decoder_pad_mask')
    print('>>>> local_decoder_pad_mask: {}'.format(local_decoder_pad_mask))
    decoder_out_func = transformer_model.decoder_fn(config=config,
                                                dec_out=decoder_gather,
                                                enc_out=encoder_tiled,
                                                encoder_pad_mask=model.encoder_pad_mask,
                                                decoder_pad_mask=local_decoder_pad_mask)  # [bs,   None, embedding_dim]
    print('>>>> decoder_out_func: {}'.format(decoder_out_func))
    # [bs, None, vocab_size]
    decoder_out = tf.matmul(decoder_out_func, model.fproj_w, transpose_b=False)
    print('>>>> decoder_out: {}'.format(decoder_out))
    decoder_out_last_step = decoder_out[:, -1, :]  # [bs, vocab_size]
    print('>>> decoder_out_last_step: {}'.format(decoder_out_last_step))
    return decoder_out_last_step
```

Could anyone help me in resolving this issue. I feel I am too close to quit. Any help to tweak the network would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

15k examples are quite little for training a transformer model from scratch. Its typical use is in machine translation where the training corpora typically have millions of sentence pairs.

You can try to tune pre-trained models:

- [Facebook's BART](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/tree/master/examples/bart) is pre-trained denoising Transformer that they used for language generation and sentence compression.
- [Hugingface's Transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) now allows combining a pre-trained encoder (like BERT) with a pre-trained language model (like GPT) and you can only train the encoder-decoder attention, they have [a tutorial on that](https://medium.com/huggingface/encoder-decoders-in-transformers-a-hybrid-pre-trained-architecture-for-seq2seq-af4d7bf14bb8).